# Sum of Column after using nest() in R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am using nest() function to create multiple models using a long dataset. After nesting, I need to find the sum of one of the columns which I have nested, and then save it as a mutated column at the nested level. Below is a similar example using the iris dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- iris %>%
    nest(-Species) %>%
    mutate(Total.Sepal.Length = map_dbl(data$Sepal.Length, sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Getting the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Total.Sepal.Length` must be length 3 (the number of rows) or one, not 0
```

Comment: @snoram - This will give an error saying "object 'Sepal.Length' not found" as it is now part of "data" column in "df"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to to it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- iris %>%
    nest(-Species) %>%
    mutate(Total.Sepal.Length = map_dbl(data, ~sum(.$Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

This is how the new column looks like:

```
# > df %>% select(-data)
#      Species Total.Sepal.Length
# 1     setosa              250.3
# 2 versicolor              296.8
# 3  virginica              329.4
```

To validate:

```
# > iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(sum(Sepal.Length))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Species    `sum(Sepal.Length)`
#   <fct>                    <dbl>
# 1 setosa                    250.
# 2 versicolor                297.
# 3 virginica                 329.
```